# Running all scenarios in a feature file, multiple times with different parameters?

Tags: c#, specflow, gherkin

Let's say I have a feature file that tests sending messages. This functionality is the same for admins, supervisors, and employees, so the same scenarios will work on the three different types of accounts. But I want to test all three kinds of accounts.

Can I set all the Scenarios in my feature to run three times, on each kind of account, only using `Background`?

I know I can do something like this:

```
Scenario Outline: Test sending messages
Given a <user>
    And some stuff here
When I click Send
Then The messages should be sent

Examples: 
| user       |
| Admin      |
| Supervisor |
| Employee   |
```

That example works, however by doing that, I have to reuse that same Examples column for every Scenario, rather than just once in the `Background`.

Comment: That is as stated in an answer not possible. It will probably never be possible either since it would be a way of using Cucumber as a pure testing tool. And it isn't a testing tool. It is a way to describe a behaviour in a system. Your option is to descibe how the system should behvae for a specific user, say Joe. And how it should behvae for the admin Cecilia. And so forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this isn't supported I don't think. This sort of functionality has been requested a few times, but I think its the gherkin syntax that doesn't support this, so it would need to be extended first I think, before specflow could be extended to support it.